# Validation on custom array - Lumen

Tags: php, arrays, validation, laravel, lumen

How can I perform validation on custom array in Lumen framework. e.g:

Example array:

```
$params   = array('name' => 'john', 'gender' => 'male');
```

I have tried something like this but didn;t work:

```
$validator = Validator::make($params, [
                                       'name' => 'required',
                                       'gender' => 'required'
                            ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {

         $messages = $validator->errors();
         $message   = $messages->first();
         echo $message;
         exit;
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Could you elaborate? Are there any errors? Is there no output from $message. What do you get from print_r($messages); when you pass it invalid data?

Comment: it doesnt perform any validation. It bypass the code

Comment: When you pass it an array of empty strings? and `print_r($messages);die()` there is no output ?

Comment: when is pass this:   $params   = array('name' => '', 'gender' => ''); it doesnt validate. In that case it should validate name

Comment: I'm not sure I know what the problem is, if I paste your code into a clean install of laravel, it works as expected. Could you update the question to more clearly describe the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Maybe you havent got error messaging turned on, $messages->first() doesn't look correct to me, since $messages should be a messagebag, try $errors = $messages->all(); and then var_dump($errors);

Comment: There is one more thing. If the fields are filled. Why it still comes inside 
if ($validator->fails()) {  check ?????

Answer (score -1):

The validation is passing because the fields are in fact present. Use something like `min` or `max`or `size` to validate the length of a string.

http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required

### Edit

I stand corrected. The `required` does actually seem to validate if it contains anything.

### Update

To clarify; the code that is supposed to run if `$validator->fails()` doesn't **ever** run if the validation passes.